# Cannot install MacVim 7.4 on OS X Maverick 10.9.4?

Tags: homebrew, macvim

I have `brew` installed (v 0.9.5) along with Xcode (Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)). When I attempt to install MacVim like so I encounter the following error message:

```
$ brew install macvim
==> Downloading https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/archive/snapshot-73.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/macvim-7.4-73.tar.gz
==> ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte --with-macarchs=x86_64 -
==> make
make[1]: *** [objects/os_mac_conv.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [objects/os_macosx.o] Error 1
make: *** [first] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
macvim failed to build on 10.9 because of x11 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/30253)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

**NOTE:** Much of what I've found seems to state that I need to install some command line component to Xcode but I wasn't able to figure out what this actually entailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue thanks to the following tip I found as to [how to install Xcode from the MacPorts page](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.xcode).

*excerpt*

> 2.1.1. Install Xcode on OS X 10.9 or later
>
> Download the latest version of Xcode [from the Apple developer
>   website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) or get it [using the Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835).
>        Once you have Xcode installed, open a terminal, run `xcode-select --install`, and click the Install button to install the required command line developer tools. Don't worry if you see a message telling
>   you the software cannot be installed because it is not currently
>   available from the Software Update Server. This usually means you
>   already have the latest version installed. You can also get the
>   command line tools from [the Apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

The key piece of information was to run this command:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

[image: ss#1]

After installing the command line tools you should be able to successfully install `macvim` using `brew`.

```
$ brew install macvim
==> Downloading https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/archive/snapshot-73.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/macvim-7.4-73.tar.gz
==> ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte --with-macarchs=x86_64 -
==> make
==> Caveats
.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps` to symlink these to /Applications.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73: 1810 files, 28M, built in 30 seconds

$ brew linkapps 
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app
Finished linking. Find the links under /Applications.
```